# For all $x$ and some of $y$

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

Prove that this works for all $x$ and and only some $y$
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2-(y+2)^2}=0.$$

This is as far as I got so far

Difference of squares:

$\sqrt{(x-1-y-2)(x-1+y+2)}=0$
$\sqrt{x-y-3}\sqrt{x+y+1}=0$

Therefore $x-y-3=0 \implies  y=x-3$

$x+y+1=0$ and $y=-1-x$

I just don't know where to go from here?

Comment: What do you mean by "this works"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, Assume the universe is the set of real numbers R. Show that the following is true. For all x, and for some y.. (above square root =0)

Comment: You basically have it already. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if we choose $y$ to be $x-3$ or $-1-x$, the two sides equate (hence "for all $x$ and some $y$").

Comment: Are you saying that, for a given $x$, there are only finite many values of $y$ that yield the equality above?? If so, your proof is shown by showing that two values of $y$ exist for each point $x$ except where the two are equal, I. E. $x-3=-1-x \implies x=1$, where there is only one solution for $y$. ( Let me know if this is what you mean...  If so I'll expand this into an answer)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to show is the following:

> For every real number $x$, there exists a real number $y$ such that 
>   $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2-(y+2)^2}=0,\tag{Eqn}$$

An equivalent way of saying "there exists a real $y$" is to say "for some real $y$". Saying "for some *of* $y$" brings to mind other things that aren't relevant. For each $x$, you only need to show that there is (at least) one $y$ satisfying (Eqn).

We write "for all x" and "there is y" using the *quantifiers* $\forall x$ and $\exists y$. In what follows, both variables $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be real numbers.

Let's rewrite what you have to show using quantifiers:
$$
(\forall x)(\exists y)\, \sqrt{(x-1)^2-(y+2)^2}=0,\tag{*}
$$
Clearly (yes?), the following statement implies (*):
$$
(\forall x)(\exists y)\, [(x-1)^2 = (y+2)^2].\tag{**}
$$

So, given $x$, simply take $y=x-3$. Then $x-1 = y+2$, so $(x-1)^2 = (y+2)^2$. This proves (**), which implies (*).

---

Your question (but not your title) says "only some", so it seems you also want to show the following:

> For every real number $x$, there exists a real number $y$ such that 
>   $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2-(y+2)^2}\ne0,\tag{not-Eqn}$$

This is also straightforward. Given $x$, here's how to find a $y$ such that (not-Eqn) is true:

- if $x \ne 1$, let $y=-2$, and
- if $x = 1$, let $y = 0$.

So the second highlighted statement is also true.

Comment: Good answer,  but probably above the OP's level of knowledge concerning math symbols (the symbols actually clear up a lot of the OP's confusing language and should thus be taught,  but you might want to explain what the symbols mean)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I took your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What you must mean (and it *really* helps to write it clearly) is that for all $x$ you can find a $y$ that makes the statement true and you can find another $y$ that makes the statement false.  So given an $x$ you can exhibit a $y$ that makes the statement true-just solve for $y$
$$(x-1)^2=(y+2)^2\\y+2=\pm(x-1)\\ y=\begin {cases}x-3\\-1-x \end{cases}$$
Either of these $y$'s will work, which you can show by plugging back in. Now let $y=x-4$, for example, to show that there is at least one $y$ that doesn't work.

Note that if you choose $y$ first, the same thing happens.  For all $y$ there are some $x$ that work and some $x$ that do not work.

Comment: I sort of get it, but why can x be any number?

Comment: Because I have succeeded in finding a $y$ (in fact, two of them) that corresponds to any $x$ and satisfies the equation.  If you give me a value for $x$, I can follow my recipe and return a value for $y$ so that the equation is true.